# How to mouse hover using javascript executor in selenium 2?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, selenium-webdriver

Currently working in Selenium WebDriver and using **Java**. I want to perform the action as mouse hover to the tab and it need to click the tab. 
Here in this code i can able to identify the element and it is opening the tab. But the problem is it is not mouse hovering and not clicking, it is directly opening the page.

```
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",                                                     
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") ));
```

If i use the

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().perform();
```

It is not exactly finding the element and it is clicking some other tab. so i want to mouse hover in javascript executor.

Comment: Please suggest any sample method to fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mouse event

```
document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
```

then assign a mouse hover to it

```
mouseEventObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, true );
```

and then dispatch it

```
element.dispatchEvent(mouseEventObj);
```